# How to specify a CSS border on hover around thumbnails?

Tags: html, css

How to correctly specify a .CSS border on hover around thumbnails? I want add external css for thumbnails, *normal:*

```
border-color: #cccccc;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

and *hover:*

```
  border-color: #0000FF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
```

html:

```
<div class="item-list"><ul id="field-slideshow-1-pager" class="field-slideshow-pager slides-4">
<li class="first"><a href="#"><img class="field-slideshow-thumbnail field-slideshow-thumbnail-1" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41MNf5JEQ1L._SL75_SS45_.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img class="field-slideshow-thumbnail field-slideshow-thumbnail-2" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/410ONnNmmJL._SL75_SS45_.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img class="field-slideshow-thumbnail field-slideshow-thumbnail-3" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41lyduCW9CL._SL75_SS45_.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="" /></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#"><img class="field-slideshow-thumbnail field-slideshow-thumbnail-4" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41VHLWxrbcL._SL75_SS45_.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

The thumbs img class have different nubmers at the end, just not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) selector:

```
.field-slideshow-thumbnail {
    border-color: #cccccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.field-slideshow-thumbnail:hover {
    border-color: #0000FF;
    /*no need to specify border-style and border-width again*/
}
```

Assuming you put the above in a file called `style.css` (in the same directory as your webpage), you need to add this inside your `<head>` for the styles to apply:

```
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css"/>
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: No need to specify the `border-width` and the `border-style` again :)

Comment: @Ana Haha, yep, thanks :) *Me blushes for making stupid mistakes.*

Comment: the 'field-slideshow-thumbnail-x' part is not relevant for style?

Comment: @fxgreen if you have multiple classes defined like `class = "class1 class2 class3"`, then your element is considered to have **all** those classes at once. So styling using `.class1` would select the element above.

Answer (score 1):

```
.field-slideshow-thumbnail 
{
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
.field-slideshow-thumbnail:hover
{
    border:solid 1px #00f;
}
```

Comment: just a note: when use such css construction? `a:hover .image
{
  border-color: #cc6600;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}`

Answer (score 1):

My solution works if the original view have no border and the hover view have border

```
.field-slideshow-thumbnail 
{
    float:left;
     /*NO BORDERS HERE*/
}
.field-slideshow-thumbnail:hover
{
    border:solid 1px #00f;
    /*NOTE that the negative value of margin to prevent the change in spaces */
    margin:-1px;
}
```